# Долгое установление соединения с Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, telnet

Есть три машины находящиеся в одной сети.
На одной крутится Mysql, две другие выступают в роли клиента.
При этом на одной клиентской машине соединение устанавливается в доли секунды, на второй то долго соединяется то быстро.
Проверял командой: telnet database.server 3306

Отличия двух клиентских машин заключаются в том что на одной стоит Ubuntu 14.04 на другой Ubuntu 16.04

Вопрос, куда копать?

Comment: А соединение как устанавливаете? Это какой-то язык, клиент?

Comment: ну вообще я столкнулся с проблемой устанавливая соединение из под jdbc. Уже потом, разбираясь в чем дело заметил что при установке соединения через телнет тот же самый эффект.

Comment: @plesser, а если использовать не имя, а ip-адрес, проблема сохраняется? // http://stackoverflow.com/q/1292856/4827341

Comment: да конечно, я сразу же это попробывал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что для каждого клиента MySQL делает DNS lookup, добавьте в конфигурацию (my.cnf) следующую строку (skip-name-resolve) в раздел mysqld и перезапустите сервер

```
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
```

Для установления причин подобных проблем изучите и пользуйтесь командой tcpdump, она Вам скажет на каком этапе случилась проблема соединения.

Comment: да это оно! спасибо